# Do I need to delete my own logs?

Tags: hacknet

I know that it's important to delete your logs on other people's systems, but I have not seen anything about deleting the log files on my own computer. I am not far enough into the game to *be* hacked, but I know it can happen. Would a hacker be able to use my logs against me? If so, do I need to delete them?

Comment: IRL? Yes. In game? Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have played though it a few times now, the first time I was extremely carful and deleted everything i possibly could so I left no trace.

Then the second time I finished it (before the dlc if that has been add yet) without deleting any of my logs

Long story short: **No you shouldn't have to delete your logs**